# How to hide custom commands without leaving space behind?

Tags: macros

For annotating documents, I've defined a command like so:

```
\DeclareDocumentCommand \commment { o m } {%
    \stepcounter{commentcounter}
    \ifhidecomments
    \else \IfNoValueTF{#1}{%
        \textsf{\textcolor{Red}{\footnotesize[Comment:\;#2]}}%
    }{%
        \textsf{\textcolor{lightgray}{\footnotesize[Comment:\;#2]}}%
    }%
    \fi
}
```

In the text you can embed a comment by doing `\comment{blah blah blah}` and it will render like `[Comment: blah blah blah]` in the text, but in red. If you want the comment to render but in gray instead (to keep it around but indicate it's been addressed), you can do `\comment[]{blah blah blah}`, i.e. pass an empty optional argument.

Now, what I want is to be able to hide all comments *without a trace* with a single command (as opposed to manually removing them). I have an if-else statement in my DocumentCommand that doesn't render the comment if `\hidecommentstrue` is specified in the document. When I used that command, indeed all the comments are hidden. Unfortunately, it can mess with the spacing between words. For instance, if I have `word1 \comment{blah} word1` and I do `\hidecommentstrue`, there's extra space between `word1` and `word2` that is not there if I actually remove the `\comment`.

Is there something I can add to my command that would fix this? Or is there no way around removing the comments manually?

Here is a minimum working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\usepackage{totcount}
\newif\ifhidecomments
\newtotcounter{commentcounter}
\setcounter{commentcounter}{0}
\DeclareDocumentCommand \comment { o m } {%
    \stepcounter{commentcounter}
    \ifhidecomments
    \else \IfNoValueTF{#1}{%
        \textsf{\textcolor{Red}{\footnotesize[Comment:\;#2]}}%
    }{%
        \textsf{\textcolor{lightgray}{\footnotesize[Comment:\;#2]}}%
    }%
    \fi
}

% \hidecommentstrue

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
\comment{this is a comment}
\lipsum[1] 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please, post a MWE with all code we need to test it. Your code does not compile.

Comment: @Sigur Apologies, added one now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is a kind of: [unexpected space because of not commented end-of-line](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7453). you can fix it either using one more percent and `\ignorespaces`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\usepackage{totcount}
\newif\ifhidecomments
\newtotcounter{commentcounter}
\setcounter{commentcounter}{0}
\DeclareDocumentCommand \comment { o m } {%
    \stepcounter{commentcounter}% <-- percent needed!
    \ifhidecomments
      \ignorespaces
    \else
    \IfNoValueTF{#1}{%
        \textsf{\textcolor{Red}{\footnotesize[Comment:\;#2]}}%
    }{%
        \textsf{\textcolor{lightgray}{\footnotesize[Comment:\;#2]}}%
    }%
    \fi
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
\comment{this is a comment}
\lipsum[1]

\hidecommentstrue
\lipsum[1]
\comment{this is a comment}
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[image]

or two more percent and one space:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\usepackage{totcount}
\newif\ifhidecomments
\newtotcounter{commentcounter}
\setcounter{commentcounter}{0}
\DeclareDocumentCommand \comment { o m } {%
    \stepcounter{commentcounter}% <-- percent needed!
    \ifhidecomments
    \else
    \IfNoValueTF{#1}{%
        \textsf{\textcolor{Red}{\footnotesize[Comment:\;#2]}}%
    }{%
        \textsf{\textcolor{lightgray}{\footnotesize[Comment:\;#2]}}%
    } % <-- space before percent added
    \fi
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
\comment{this is a comment}%
\lipsum[1]

\hidecommentstrue
\lipsum[1]
\comment{this is a comment}%
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

BTW: With the shown definition, if would IMHO make more sense to define, a `\comment` with star variant, e.g.,

```
\DeclareDocumentCommand \comment { s m } {%
    \stepcounter{commentcounter}% <-- percent needed!
    \ifhidecomments
    \else
    \IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
        \textsf{\textcolor{lightgray}{\footnotesize[Comment:\;#2]}}%
    }{%
        \textsf{\textcolor{Red}{\footnotesize[Comment:\;#2]}}%
    } % <-- space before percent added
    \fi
}
```

instead of using testing for an empty optional argument.

Comment: Amazing, it worked like a charm! I decided to go with `\ignorespaces` (and of course adding the needed `%` as well), just because it seems clearer when looking over the code what's actually happening.

Comment: Also using a star seems like a better idea for sure, thanks!